# Program about ask to write teams and points, save them and show the result (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop

I have tried to make a program that works like this:

I request to write matches of a paddle league in this format:

```
{TeamNameA} {TeamWonSetsA} {TeamNameB} {TeamWonSetsB}
```

All of that is written on the same line, **but each match is written on a different line**. In each match, the team with the most sets wins. Every time a team wins a match, they add 3 points, and if they lose, 0.
I must save the names of all the teams that I write because a team can appear in different matches. In addition, as a team can appear in several matches, I also have to save and update their score (if they have won 1 match, they will have 3 points , but if they later wins another match, it will increase to 6 points).
I have to enter matches all the time until I enter the word END, and at that time it will stop asking me for matches and will show the results with the winner (which will be the team with the most points), and then it will show a ranking of team scores.

Since it is somewhat confusing, I give you an example: I am going to enter 3 matches and then the word END, and then it will show the results:

```
Gachon 1 PitGuss 4
//As the "PitGuss" team has more sets, they win the match and get 3 points

Picasos 2 Redbull 3
//The "Redbull" team wins, for which they get 3 points

PitGuss 4 Shirts 3
//The PitGuss team wins again, so they now have 6 points

END
//When entering this, the program stops asking me for matches and displays the results

Winning team: "PitGuss"
League Results:
PitGuss- 6 points
Redbull - 3 points
Gachon - 0 points
//The ranking is of the 3 best teams, so it isn't necessary to put all the teams with 0 points
```

And basically that would be the program, put several matches until writing END, the teams earn points by winning matches, and then show the result with a ranking of 3 teams maximum.

This is what I have of code:

```
while team1 != END:
    team1, points1, team2, points2 = input().split()
    if points1 > points2
        team1punct = 3
    else:
        team2punct = 3
else:
    print("Winning team:")
    print("League Results:")
```

Basically what I have is very little, because no matter how much I search in Google and on this page, I don't understand how the "while" works in Python for constantly asking me for matches until I put END, to save the teams and points maybe I could use a bidimensional array, but I don't know exactly how to fill the array when entering the data (teams and points). And well, in the part where I print the results I haven't written any team either because to begin with I don't know how to select the winning team if I don't know how to add points when they win matches.

I know I'm asking for a lot of help, but I've been searching and learning about Python and I can't make this program, so if someone could help me I'd be incredibly grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be too helpful but I hope it helps you understand the while loop further;

```
while True: #Will re-iterate until closed by choice
    teamANDscore = [] #Resets teams and scores stored
    for x in range(2): #Gets 2 teams and their scores respectively
        teamANDscore.append([input("Team " + str(x+1) + " Name: "), input("Team " + str(x+1) + " Sets Won: ")])
    if teamANDscore[0][1] > teamANDscore[1][1]: #If first team wins
        print(teamANDscore[0][0] + " won and gained 3 points!")
    elif teamANDscore[0][1] < teamANDscore[1][1]: #If second team wins
        print(teamANDscore[0][0] + " won and gained 3 points!")
    else:
        print("It was a draw!")

    #To stop re-iterating you must use break
    break
```

That would show one way of checking which team has won a match, hope it helps.